# jQuery parseHTML set prop('selected', true)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the code similar to the following to make a select list, then choose one of the options and select it. And finally, get the result back to a string.

```js
var newHtml = "<div id='divname' class='column column-one'>" +
                        selectlabel +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='column column-two'>" +
                        "<select id='selectlist'>" +
                        "<option value='0'></option>" +
                        "<option value='1'>Option 2</option>" +
                        "<option value='2'>Option 3</option>" +
                        "<option value='3'>Option 4</option>" +
                        "<option value='4'>Option 5</option>" +
                        "</select>" +
                        "</div>";
                    
newHtml = $($.parseHTML(newHtml)).find("#selectlist option").eq(1).prop('selected', true).get(0).outerHTML;
```

`newHtml` winds up equal to `"<option value="1">Option 2</option>"`

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why isn't `selected` being set properly on the `option`?
2. What is the code necessary to get the whole, updated html string back out?

Comment: I dont believe using `.prop` actually updates the HTML - use `.attr` for that.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below

1.Use .attr('selected','selected') instead of .prop()
2.Use on change function and use $(this) to get the updated and selected option

```
var newHtml = "<div id='divname' class='column column-one'>selectLabel</div>" +
  "<div class='column column-two'>" +
  "<select id='selectlist'>" +
  "<option value='0'></option>" +
  "<option value='1'>Option 2</option>" +
  "<option value='2'>Option 3</option>" +
  "<option value='3'>Option 4</option>" +
  "<option value='4'>Option 5</option>" +
  "</select>" +
  "</div>";

$(newHtml).appendTo('body');

$('#selectlist').on('change', function() {

  $(this).attr("selected", "selected");

})
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZOPZbp

Comment: Wound up doing similar to what you said. Added the HTML to the doc, then in a second pass change the selected value to the one I want via .attr("selected", "selected")

Comment: Thanks @BrianTempleton ..glad that my answer helped your question :)